# Pass values of jTable into jComboBox when row selected

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to pass data of selectedRow from jTable into jTextField and into jComboBox.

For jTextField every row I select it automatically fills the jTextFields but for jComboBox part when I select a row, it fills correctly but when I select another row it sticks with the first selected data and I want to pass data of any selected row:

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
   int SelectedRowIndex = jTable1.getSelectedRow();  
   String sid = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 1);
   jComboBox2.addItem(sid);
   jTextField1.setText((String) jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 2));
   jTextField3.setText((String) jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 3));
   jTextField2.setText((String) jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 12));  
}
```

Comment: Please post a valid testable [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

First of all variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of your variable names are correct and some are not. Learn the Java conventions and use them properly.

> but when i select another row it sticks with the first selected data

I would guess that the combobox is empty when you start. Then when you add the first item, it gets selected automatically.

But adding additional items does not change the selection.

So I would suggest your code should be:

```
jComboBox2.addItem(sid);
jComboBox2.setSelectedIten(sid);
```